# SSL Certifacte is Invalid because of Content Mismatch?

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I'm working for a new client that recently added a COMODO SSL Cert. He made his website with a different developer a long time ago and the back-end part of the WordPress website is mostly broken...

I tried to change posts, images, links etc to https but I still can't find a way to make it Display the Green Lock without spitting errors...

Spent quite a few hours trying to make it work and hope a fresh pair of eyes and a different perspective could easily help me identify what needs to be done to make the domain accept SSL.

Here is the domain
https://investigatiiprivate.ro/

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: did you check the `website_url` in the `wp-admin` section? Did you or the old developer set any `prefix_url's` in the source code? Did you check the `options.php` file (can be loaded while logged in to the `/wp-admin` area)?

Comment: In `wp-admin/Settings:` 
`WordPress Address (URL) = https://investigatiiprivate.ro`,
`Site Address (URL) = https://investigatiiprivate.ro`.

If i go to https://investigatiiprivate.ro/wp-options I get redirected to the main page.

Comment: Go to: https://investigatiiprivate.ro/options.php

Comment: Still getting redirect to `https://investigatiiprivate.ro`

Comment: that means that `.htaccess` is blocking those url's from accessing them. You could change that to access these pages. Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: Complete .htaccess settings - https://pastebin.com/Ak8sfFwu

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Deathstorm, the problem was mainly because it had a few Redirect plugins like `All 404 Redirect to Homepage`, `Redirect`